# UIScreen returns wrong value?

Tags: objective-c

```
NSLog(@"-- %f %f",[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width,[UIScreen    mainScreen].bounds.size.height);
```

is : `-- 320.000000 568.000000` , `-- 320.000000 480.000000` for `iPhone 5 /4` respectively .

The app has all the `Default` images needed . and its universal .
(`Default.png, Default@2x.png, and Default-568h@2x.png`, `480x320, 960x640, and 1136x640` )

Why i keep getting this wrong values ? ( i have cleaned,restart  ) .

Comment: They seem correct, what are you expecting to see? Or are you talking about another values?

Comment: i am expecting to see 320 , 640 , and 640 for all widths . isn't it what i should get ?

Comment: You can check window height with below code for different devices.#define isiPhone5  ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)?YES:NO

Comment: Not actually, since the difference between retina and non-retina isn't about the width, it's about pixels. So, you're getting the correct values.

Comment: _pixels_ are __not__ equal to _points_.

Answer (score 0):

I think, what you need to check is for retina display

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]
    && [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.0) 
{
    // Retina
     NSLog(@"-- %f %f",2*[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width,2*[UIScreen    mainScreen].bounds.size.height);
}
else 
{
    // Not Retina
    NSLog(@"-- %f %f",[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width,[UIScreen    mainScreen].bounds.size.height);
}
```

Comment: that is a good idea, But i have written this to make understand to new developers....

Comment: Don't hardcode the scale. Just use `NSLog(@"-- %f %f",[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width * [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale],[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height * [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);`

Answer (score 0):

Those are the correct values.

iOS works in points - not pixels. This is to make it easier to work with sizing and position with different scale displays.

Eg: an iPhone 3Gs at 1x scale has a width of 320 points (which happens to conincide with 320 pixels that the display physically has), then iPhone 4 came along with the retina display (at 2x scale) where its width is still 320 points, but works out to be 640 physical pixels. The screen renders the UI twice the size as the 3Gs, but fit its into the same physical space. Because of the increased pixel density, this increases the quality of the display.

So whenever you are working with sizing and positioning, think in points and remember to factor in the scale of the display they will be shown on. When working with images the scale is important so make sure to understand when to use @2x images for retina display.

Answer (score -1):

You can check window height with below code for different devices. Just use below code.

```
#define isiPhone5  ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)?YES:NO
 if (isiPhone5) { 
//This is iPhone5, 5S

} else {
//This is iPhone4, 4S

}
```

OR to check it is iPad or iPhone see this

```
#define IS_IPAD ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
```

I hope this will help to know what you want.